# How to avoid eval for string to decimal conversion

Tags: javascript, eval

I have "1/7" and want to get decimal equivalent. Ofcourse I can use eval( "1/7"), but considering eval is evil, any other method?

Comment: var result = 1/7; - what is the problem?

Comment: @Baku he want the result to be 0.1428 meaning divide those numbers.

Comment: There really isn't anything wrong with using *eval* for this, it's what it's meant for.

Comment: @RobG but if the input is coming from the user, it's just asking hackers to come in.

Comment: Hackers can insert code and eval it anyway, the user can enter it in the address field, a debugger or a plugin like Greasemonkey. The security issue is allowing such code to be sent to a server or served to other users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own function, it's not really complicated and pretty efficient:

```
function ParseFloat(sFloat) {
    var parts = sFloat.split("/");
    if (parts.length == 2) {
        var first = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
        var second = parseInt(parts[1], 10);
        if (!isNaN(first) && !isNaN(second))
            return first / second;
    }
    return NaN;
}
```

Usage:

```
var s = "1/7";
alert(ParseFloat(s));
```

Live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/RK3zS/

Edit: if you're after working with such entities, I would use "class" for this for example:

```
function DecimalFraction(first, second) {
    this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
    this.toString = function() {
        return first / second;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
var s = new DecimalFraction(3, 7);
alert(s);
```

More elegant in my opinion. Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RK3zS/1/).

Comment: Shadow - there is no need for parseInt, division will convert the strings to numbers anyway. Also the use of a constructor that returns such a trivial result is a very inefficient way of handling the problem.

Comment: @Rob but I want to have it more flexible and know when it fails - right now my example just returns `NaN` as well, but it can also handle such thing and show some message instead. Regarding `toString()` it's defined only once and can't see why it's inefficient, sorry.

Answer (score 6):

eval is not evil.  It's only evil to use it on arbitrary strings without checking your input.

Answer (score 1):

That's the only option we have, I guess. Eval is not that evil too. Else create own function to identify values and do calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have to calculate decimals and only decimals:

```
txt = "1/7";

firstNumber = txt.subString(0, txt.indexOf('/'));
secondNumber = txt.subString(txt.indexOf('/') + 1, txt.length);

decml = fistNumber / secondNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

try it like this.

```
var txt = "1/7";
var result = new Function("return " + txt)()
console.log(result); // 0.14285714285714285
```

Comment: Pretty much like `eval` as it's effectively evaluating the string.